# XSLT for namespace elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Having input XML in the below format:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header/>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ResponseData xmlns="http://testify.com/maxi">
      <VALID>true</VALID>
      <ERROR_DESC xsi:nil="true"> something gone wrong </ERROR_DESC>
    </ResponseData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Its getting difficult to convert this into below format because of its complexity due to namespaces.

```
<STATUS>
  <VALID> TRUE </VALID>
  <ERROR_DESC> something gone wrong  </ERROR_DESC>
</STATUS>
```

I have tried several options without success. Below resulting no data.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="s:Envelope//s:Body/s:ResponseData"/>
</xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="s:ResponseData">
    <xsl:element name="width">
      <xsl:value-of select="s:VALID"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you want `<STATUS>` as the wrapper, then why are you asking for `<xsl:element name="width">` ?!

Answer (score 3):

To get the result specified in your question, you need to:

(a) use the correct namespace when addressing the `ResponseData` element and its children; and
 (b) actually process the children of `ResponseData`by applying templates to them.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:m="http://testify.com/maxi"
exclude-result-prefixes="m">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="m:ResponseData">
    <STATUS>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </STATUS>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:*">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that nothing is being copied in order not to copy the namespaces.